# email to php - working with large attachments

Tags: php, email, pipe, mime

Using this tutorial [Use Email Piping to Save Email Attachments](http://www.damnsemicolon.com/php/php-parse-emails-email-piping-attachments-part-3) I'm on the way to making my own posterous type app - however, when I send large attachments (over 10k), they don't get uploaded? Everything else works a treat!

Is there some php.ini setting I've missed, or something to do with the max time on the php 
script?

EDIT: it would seem that the issues is in fact sending image files (jpg/pdf) from Apple's Mail client is the issue as it works fine using googlemail - Must have something to do with Mail putting the files in the main body??

Many thanks

Comment: PHP memory, receiving server attachment size limit, etc... lots of options. 10k seems a ludicrously small limit, though.

Comment: Try save whole email content to file and see it's size. Maybe your script even don't receive whole email from your mail server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the comments - turns out the issue was only inline attachments (i.e. sent from apple mail) and the script wasn't interpreting them.